# How to register apicontroller & controller route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, controller, asp.net-apicontroller

I need to use the following route for all the basic controller of my project :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and the following route for all the apicontroller action :

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I register those route by using the following code :

```
        // Code that runs on application startup
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); 
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

if i register WebApiConfig first, the actions in all the controllers are not found.
But if i register RouteTable first, the api endpoint in the apicontroller are not found.

either way it seems like one is erased by the other.

Did i missed something ?
Thanks for any help !

Comment: You will get a route conflict. API routes are usually prefixed with something to avoid conflicting with MVC routes for example `"api/{controller}/{id}"`. I suggest you register the API routes first with a prefix and then the MVC routes.

Comment: I did what you suggested. So now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nkosi suggested, i resolved the conflict by prefixing my API routes like : "api/{controller}/{id}